# How to collect checked radio buttons and put in array then post to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, .net-core

I'm setting up a form for user. I gather questions and options from server and wantto collect andswers in array then post it to controller and array should look like this :

```
[{"selection": "A", "question_id": "13"}, {"selection": "A", "question_id": "14"}]
```

I get values from controller and can alert selected radio buttons without array.

Here is my view :

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
   <tr>
      <td>@item.Order</td>
      <td>@Html.Raw(item.Body)</td>

   @{var opt = item.QuizesOption.Where(m => m.QuestionId==item.Id).ToList();}
   @for (int i = 0; i < opt.Count(); i++)
   {
      <td width="200">
    <input type="radio" class="mybox" value="selection:@opt[i].Order,question_id:@item.Id"><label>@opt[i].Body</label>

       </td>

    }
    </tr>
  }
```

Here is my simple Js

```
var selected = new Array();

$('#save_value').click(function() {
  $('.mybox:checked').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

So I can get value seperatly but I need to put it in array as shown format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `push` in your current code:

```
var selected = new Array();
$("#save_value").click(function() {
  $(".mybox:checked").each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: it directly puts in like selection:A,question_id:77 how can I modify it look like [{"selection": "A", "question_id": "13"}, {"selection": "A", "question_id": "14"}]

Comment: also it adds 1 by 1 alerts each time. should I use for or sth to prevent duplicate ?

Comment: @Jackal You may only have one checkbox checked - my code will extract the values of multiple checkboxes.

Comment: yea I put alert in wrong place. but the problem is it comes out like this selection:A,question_id:75,selection:A,question_id:76 like 4 elements I need to divide 2 parts like  [{"selection": "A", "question_id": "13"}, {"selection": "A", "question_id": "14"}]